# how to access public folder with docker compose from another image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to access the public from client image inside my api image
i tried to add a volume to the api image but it doesn't work

```
- ./client/public:/app
```

full compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
      - ./client/public:/app
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    links:
      - api
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this way, your /APP will overwrite by client's public directory and the API will not be able to access its own files.
Instead, you should mount the client's public folder to a different location in the API image. For example, you could mount it to /client_public

```
volumes:
 
  - ./client/public:/client_public
```

Comment: well I tried to add this to my server image but still I cannot access it's files